# Artifacts issue only from today, how to fix that?

Tags: amazon-s3, gitlab, gitlab-ci

No issue till today.
No change in the pipeline code also.

But artifacts are not uploading.

My pipeline job.

```
build-rpm:
  stage: build_preconfig
  image: ubuntu:latest
  rules:
    #- if: '$PACKAGE_URL && $PACKAGE_URL != ""'
    #  when: never
    - if: "$ACTION && $BUILDRPMREQUIRED" #should run for default when
    - when: never #should skip as default condition
  variables:
    RPMVERSION: nightlye2e
  cache:
    key: apt-cache
    paths:
      - apt-cache/
  before_script:
    - *install_build_dependencies
    - *configure_aws_cli
  script:
    - ./build.py --version ${RPMVERSION} --all --profile default --dev
    - echo "RPM file generated for version $RPMVERSION "
    - mv ./dist/*.rpm ./dist/pipeline.rpm
    - aws s3 ls --profile $ACCOUNT_NAME
    - account_id=`aws sts get-caller-identity --profile $ACCOUNT_NAME --query "Account" --output text`
    - bucketstatus=$(aws s3api head-bucket --bucket "projectn-rpm-${account_id}-${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}" --profile $ACCOUNT_NAME 2>&1) || true
    - echo $bucketstatus
    - |+
      #if [ $(aws s3 ls "s3://projectn-rpm-${account_id}-${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}" --profile $ACCOUNT_NAME | grep 'NoSuchBucket' &> /dev/null) == 0 ]
      if echo "${bucketstatus}" | grep 'Not Found';
      then 
        echo "No old buckets"
      else
        echo "Removing old bucket: projectn-rpm-${account_id}-${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}"
        aws s3 rm s3://projectn-rpm-${account_id}-${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} --profile $ACCOUNT_NAME --recursive
        aws s3 rb --force s3://projectn-rpm-${account_id}-${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} --profile $ACCOUNT_NAME
      fi
    - bucket=`aws s3api create-bucket --bucket projectn-rpm-${account_id}-${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} --region ${REGION} --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=${REGION} --acl private --profile ${ACCOUNT_NAME}`
    - bucketurl=$(echo $bucket | /usr/bin/jq --raw-output '.Location')
    - aws s3 cp ./dist/pipeline.rpm s3://projectn-rpm-${account_id}-${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}/ --acl public-read --profile $ACCOUNT_NAME
    - s3url="${bucketurl}pipeline.rpm"
    - echo $s3url > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/s3url.txt
    - cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/s3url.txt
  artifacts:
    untracked: false
    paths:
      - "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/s3url.txt"
```

Last part of script checks whether file exists or not by cat of the text file and it worked.

But in the artifacts part, it is not able to upload file.

[image: gitlab cat of s3url]

Answer (score 0):

`artifacts:paths:` is already relative to `CI_PROJECT_DIR` so you shouldn't include it in the artifact paths.

Change

```yaml
  artifacts:
    untracked: false
    paths:
      - "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/s3url.txt"
```

to

```yaml
  artifacts:
    untracked: false
    paths:
      - s3url.txt
```

Comment: Yeah I get that, but it worked earlier, why it is failing now